# Menu doesnt open when i click button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

when I click on the menu button my menu isn't opening on mobile.

Here is the code I am using:

```js
$('#responsive-menu-button').click(function() {
    if($('#responsive-menu-container').hasClass('slide-left')) {
        $(this).removeClass('slide-left');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('slide-left');
    }
$('#responsive-menu-container').toggle();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="responsive-menu-button" class="responsive-menu-button responsive-menu-accessible responsive-menu-boring" type="button" aria-label="Menu"><span class="responsive-menu-box"><span class="responsive-menu-inner"></span></span></button>

    <div id="responsive-menu-container" class="
      slide-left  ">
      <div id="responsive-menu-wrapper">
        <div id="responsive-menu-title">Menu</div><ul id="responsive-menu" class=""><li id="responsive-menu-item-12" class=" menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-7 current_page_item responsive-menu-item responsive-menu-current-item"><a href="http://www.fanfarejulianarossum.nl/" class="responsive-menu-item-link">Home</a></li></ul><div id="responsive-menu-search-box">
            <form action="http://www.fanfarejulianarossum.nl" class="responsive-menu-search-form" role="search">
              <input type="search" name="s" placeholder="Search" class="responsive-menu-search-box">
            </form>
          </div>  </div>
    </div>
```

I cant find the answer anywhere, I need to remove the class on `responsive-menu-container` when I click on the button `responsive-menu-button`

Comment: And, as always, I will ask "why are you using js for this?".

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `touchstart` event

```
$('#responsive-menu-button').on('click touchstart', function() {
    if($('#responsive-menu-container').hasClass('slide-left')) {
        $(this).removeClass('slide-left');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('slide-left');
    }
    $('#responsive-menu-container').toggle();
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but it still doesnt work. It also doesnt work when i resize my window

Comment: I realised that you don't have the closing brackets in your question, are you getting any error

Answer (score 0):

Check what $( this ) is in your code. It seems that $( this ) is $( '#responsive-menu-button' ) not $( '#responsive-menu-container' ), so you add the .slide-left class to the button, not the container.

```js
$('#responsive-menu-button').click(function() {
  if ($('#responsive-menu-container').hasClass('slide-left')) {
    $('#responsive-menu-container').removeClass('slide-left');
  } else {
    $('#responsive-menu-container').addClass('slide-left');
  }
  $('#responsive-menu-container').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="responsive-menu-button" class="responsive-menu-button responsive-menu-accessible responsive-menu-boring" type="button" aria-label="Menu"><span class="responsive-menu-box"><span class="responsive-menu-inner"></span></span>
</button>

<div id="responsive-menu-container" class="
  slide-left  ">
  <div id="responsive-menu-wrapper">
    <div id="responsive-menu-title">Menu</div>
    <ul id="responsive-menu" class="">
      <li id="responsive-menu-item-12" class=" menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-7 current_page_item responsive-menu-item responsive-menu-current-item"><a href="http://www.fanfarejulianarossum.nl/" class="responsive-menu-item-link">Home</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="responsive-menu-search-box">
      <form action="http://www.fanfarejulianarossum.nl" class="responsive-menu-search-form" role="search">
        <input type="search" name="s" placeholder="Search" class="responsive-menu-search-box">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Your code seems to work correctly, as you have $('#responsive-menu-container').toggle() at the end, but I think this is misleading - it only covers other errors.

Answer (score 0):

try with this...

```
 $('#responsive-menu-button').click(function() {
        if($('#responsive-menu-container').hasClass('slide-left')) {
            $(this).removeClass('slide-left');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('slide-left');
        }

    $('#responsive-menu-container').toggle();
  });
```

find your code here its working correctly https://jsfiddle.net/1w57uxx3/